# Makefile Conditionals erroneous equality

Tags: if-statement, makefile

So, I'm kind of new to makefiles, but I have this rule in mine:

```
$(rc)/%.class: $(r)/%.java
    echo $(strip $(findstring $*,"Robot RoboController"))
ifneq (,$(strip $(findstring $*,"Robot RoboController")))
    echo "Robot or RoboController"
else
    echo "other";
endif
```

My goal, is that if the matched text is Robot or RoboController, then it compiles in one way, otherwise, it compiles in a different way, unforunately, when I run makes I get the following output:

```
$ make Classes/RobotSuite/robot/Robot.class
    echo Robot
    Robot
    echo "other";   
    other
$ make Classes/RobotSuite/robot/RoboComm.class
    echo 

    echo "other";   
    other
```

It seems like no matter what I put into the `ifneq`, it will erroneously evaluate it as equal to the null string.  Can anyone explain why?

I am using the GNU Make v3.81, built for i686-pc-linux-gnu.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "java"?

Comment: Whoops.  Poor choice.  Wasn't really paying attention.

Comment: Hey, is there any way to bump this thread, without being a dick about it?

Comment: You can delete the question and resubmit it. It might help if you explained what make system you are using.

Comment: I can post a decent answer, if you want. Why do you want to "bump this thread" (and what do you mean by that phrase)?

Comment: @Beta - I'd really like that - I feel like that's why we submit questions :c)  And "Bumping" a thread is a way of bringing it to the forefront so that people will see it.  I prefer to do it with new information, so that people don't get annoyed by seeing a repeatedly bumped thread.

Comment: I've never understood people using make for Java, at least any more.

Comment: It's actually really useful if you're Developing with a group that normally uses IDEs.  It allows you to set flags for compilation - and specifically here, I'm compiling for the Lejos OS on the NXT Brick, and they have their own VM, and thus compiler.  Instead of telling end user "Compile with a bunch of long commands", I can say "Type make".  Make is also much better at detecting updated source files.  I've had several instances of java not recompiling a class depended upon, and this is just easier at the command line.

Comment: I see, and I see why I didn't get it before-- it's really against the culture of this forum, don't do it. Anyway, target-specific variable values are the way to go if they suffice for your case, and you seem satisfied with Brian Cain's answer; for the more general case you can have a conditional in the makefile (in Make syntax) or within a command (in shell syntax).

Comment: @Beta  Yeah, it's usually a pretty obnoxious thing to do, so I try not to do it without at least rewording the question with more info to help people answer the question.  Some forums provide a mechanism by which to do it so that people know it's been bumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GNU Make, don't use `ifneq` to solve this problem, use [Target specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Target_002dspecific.html).